# Array being mysteriously converted to object immediately before usort() sees it

Tags: php, arrays, object, type-conversion, usort

I'm getting a good laugh out of this situation. It's in a giant application, so I can't just upload everything, but here is the local, relevant part of my code:

```

```
public function reallyCustomSort($thing, $options='')
{
    die('dying. gettype results for our param: '.gettype($thing));
    //Gives us "array." So why does usort complain about "object given?"
    die('dying. get_class results for our param: '.get_class($thing)); // Gives us "get_class() expects parameter 1 to be object, array given.
    usort($thing, 'AppBundle\Twig\CustomSort::customCompare'); // Gives us "Warning: usort() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given"
    die('We are done here.');
    return($thing);
}

public function someRandomFunction($thing){
    die('dying in someRandomFunction. gettype results for our param: '.gettype($thing)); //Gives us "array."
}
```

```

In other words, two function calls that analyze my variable both agree that it's an array, and then a line later, my usort() function thinks that the variable contains an object.

**Has anyone ever encountered this behavior before? If so, how did you get around it?**

A few things I've already tried:

- Inserting a sleep() call to see if race conditions are involved. (See
  gist below.) No luck.
- Passing the `$thing` variable to a different function just to see if
  for some strange reason the mere passing of the `$thing` to a
  function was causing a conversion. No luck.
- Clearing various caches in my app. No luck.

A gist with some more (commented out) code showing things I've tried:

https://gist.github.com/patrickmaynard/7c3c7f0695e223e6903fd729172b4c21

Comment: Hard to tell what's going on and what's not because a lot of that code is commented out. Can you provide an example that shows only lines that actually matter please?

Comment: See also: http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php ~ Make sure the data you're working with is not being manipulated 'by reference', which can lead to confusion like this.

Comment: `usort()` does work 'by reference', but it doesn't convert an array to an object, so I don't think it's the source of the problem. It's happening somewhere before you call `usort()`.

Comment: Good point. I'll try defining a test function that receives the variable by reference. Maybe the mere act of passing by reference is playing a role here. (Update: Nope, that wasn't the issue. As you suspected, it's elsewhere.) Thanks for the earlier answers, btw -- I went ahead and cleaned up the snippet at your suggestion. Good call.

Answer (score 0):

I got around the issue by just writing a custom function, based heavily on an SO answer elsewhere. Here's the gist:

https://gist.github.com/patrickmaynard/922cf7cfa7533c655ec1c5eb4303345a

(The array I'm sorting is an array of objects, each of which has a getName() method. So the logic in this gist works relatively well for my use case. It will probably require some adaptation for others.)

====

Edit: Someone I respect also noticed that my method was being called more than once, which meant that a standalone die() function was not the best way to debug it. It was receiving an array the first time around, then receiving an object the second or third time. So while the workaround above "works," we were able to find a more elegant solution by observing the object type that was being passed during those later method calls, then using that object's toArray() method.